# Help with conditional mean in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having the following problem:

If text values are similar in Column B then gather $$ values found in Column M and display the mean of those fields in Column N.

Comment: Do realise, that the problem you described has nothing to do a script or conditional formatting.

Comment: @Tina:  What do you mean by similar?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula to accomplsh this.

### Formula

```
=SUMIF(B:B,UNIQUE(B:B),M:M)
```

### Explained

The `UNIQUE` function will get the unique entries. The `SUMIF` will sum `M:M` if one of the entries, given by the `UNIQUE` formula, matches in `B:B`.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[SUMIF range](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdHhUVmJ3LWFKWmZTSmx3OFJvczItZ0E&usp=sharing)**